# Launch window from NSView subclass in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to launch a window in an NSView subclass by clicking a NSRect? I have tried makeKeyAndOrderFront but this doesn't work.

Comment: How are you creating the window? It would help if you showed the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't click on a rectangle. A rectangle is just four numbers.

You can have an NSView that responds to clicks, but you should consider using NSButton instead. If you really want a custom view, you can both create the button and add it as a subview of your view programmatically. Then, set the button's target to yourself and its action to the selector of a message you'll respond to by opening the window.

One more thing: You don't launch a window. Windows aren't applications and applications aren't windows. On Mac OS X, applications *have* windows—always more than one (counting at least the About panel). So, you'll load the window from a nib, then make it key (respond to events) and order it front.

On that point: You probably should not have your view owning a window. Consider making a controller object to own the window instead, and having your view simply forward the message to the controller object (or even hook the button up to the controller directly).